# How do you avoid Kubernetes environment variable collisions

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, dockerfile

Presuming you have a Kubernetes cluster with SVC_A that references another service(Postgres in this case) via an environment variables

```
: "${POSTGRES_HOST:="postgres"}"
: "${POSTGRES_PORT:="5432"}"
```

`POSTGRES_PORT` is there a way to avoid the collision of the auto-generated environment variables without changing the service name `postgres` as this would alter the DNS lookup within the cluster that other services are referring too.

I am aware I could manually set environment variables on the referring services Kubernetes deployment sections but I'd like to avoid this as this seems laborious and error-prone when there are multiple containers referring to the service(Postgres)

relevant service definition from Kubernetes YAML file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: airflow
    tier: db
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: postgrestest
```

Exported environment variables when the referring pod container

```
declare -x POSTGRES_PORT="tcp://10.100.0.208:5432"
declare -x POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP="tcp://10.100.0.208:5432"
declare -x POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR="10.100.0.208"
declare -x POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT="5432"
declare -x POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO="tcp"
declare -x POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST="10.100.0.208"
declare -x POSTGRES_SERVICE_PORT="5432"
declare -x POSTGRES_SERVICE_PORT_POSTGRES="5432"
```

Comment: You could try [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Comment: specifying a namespace does not seem to change the environment variables that were exported and the issue still persists.

Comment: _specifying a namespace does not seem to change the environment variables that were exported_ is patently untrue. Every `Service` except `kubernetes` is scoped to the namespace in which it is defined. I believe what @stacksonstacks was correctly saying is to move your app that is jammed up by those variables into its own namespace, and then contact the postgres service either via its full cluster DNS name `postgres.${ns}.svc.custer.local` replacing `${ns}` as needed

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel While I agree the change you described in  DNS name-spacing did occur, what you describe as patently untrue is a completely different behavior than what I had stated in my previous comment. The behavior of exporting of the Environment Variables such as `POSTGRES_PORT` which is what is conflicting with scripts running within my Docker containers is what I, maybe unclearly, was searching for a solution for.  I had hoped name-spacing might have change the variables such that it would look something to the affect of `${NS}_POSTGRESS_TRUE`. Sorry, if that was not clear.

Comment: @CrisFavero did you find a solution?

Comment: @milosjovac I no longer have access to the project I was working on at that time, so I cannot verify what we decided upon as a solution, however, I believe the result was just that we changed our entire naming scheme so the conflict would not occur.